# How can I get an integer out of a String with sections

Tags: string, substring, trim, parseint

I try to get an integer (right after "PLAYING:STATION\nID:"out of the String shown in my screenshot by using the following code:

```
 int zahl = Integer.parseInt(sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf("PLAYING:STATION\n
ID:")+1).trim());
```

But all I get is a NumberFormatException. How can I tell the trim()-method that it has to stop right after the number?

[Screenshot of the complete String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpnyg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you must select a specific `ID:` entry among several ones, I think the best way to proceed is using a regular expression. Using your output sample, I wrote the following code:

```
String text = "PLAYING_MODE\nID:\nPLAYING:STATION\nID:2\nNAME:wazee.org";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("PLAYING:STATION\nID:(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
  int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
  System.out.println(number);
}
```

which correctly parses the `ID` number that immediately follows `PLAYING_STATION`.

You could as well repeatedly work with the overloaded `String.indexOf()` method (find `PLAYING:STATION`, then the following `ID:`, then the following `\n`). I think the code might be harder to read, but it would still do the job.

I hope this will be helpful...

Cheers,

Jeff